# colorbox jquery not displaying html

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have tried both using an element (div) on the page as well as direct inline html:

```
$.colorbox({width:"50%", html:'<p>This is my text</p>'});
$('#create_project').submit();
```

the box shows up but html does not. No errors. This is in chrome although not sure if it matters.

Comment: My advice - make jsfiddle - and you get answer in 20 minutes!

Comment: ok, show me - when you include colorbox library - cos it is not jquery native @user2009606

Comment: must be something else on that page as it is working in jsfiddle.  Not my code trying to fix. Maybe css.... not sure really what to look, but I guess will have to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: U need colorbox library inlcude!